# how to connect PCI express NIC for ethernet in mini-PCIe slot?

Tags: network-adapter, pci-express, minipci

I am using a NIC that has hardware timestamping feature and I want to use that. Is there is any way that I can connect a PCI express NIC (intel I210) for ethernet to a mini PCIe(IMX 6 sabre sd board) slot without facing more delay while transmission ?

Comment: Well, sure. But where would you even place the card if you only have Mini-PCIe?

Comment: I am thinking about some PCIe to mini PCIe converter, will it work ?

Comment: Have you tried searching for mini PCIe to PCIe adaptors? https://www.amazon.co.uk/Mini-PCIe-PCI-adapter-Riser/dp/B00HUV4NUK

Comment: yes I did, I wanted to know whether it will add more delay if so, any other means are possble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mini PCIe slot provides a full single PCI express channel. There is no need for electrical adaptation, only physical, therefore there should be no delay introduced by any adapter other than the standard inductance/capacitance issues involved with a longer electrical path.